# parent site not showing in breadcrumb in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

How to show the parent site link, like home in breadcrumb in sharepoint 2013 when  i am in sub site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see here, is a possible solution for you.
Replace this:

```
<SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitle"><SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" /></SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
```

with:

```
<asp:SiteMapPath
     runat="server"
     SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider"
     RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false"
     NodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbNode"
     CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbCurrentNode"
     RootNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbRootNode"
     HideInteriorRootNodes="true"
     SkipLinkText=""/>
```

In the master page

Visit https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11480/breadcrumb-not-showing-parent-site

Comment: I tried this one. No luck. is there any other solution?